# Custom Domain Ownership is Not Getting Verified in Azure for App Services

Tags: service, dns

I had purchased a domain name with GoDaddy. after subscribing as a Pay as you go, I added the domain in the AAD. I verified the domain name as well, and mapped the named server to the NS records of Azure.

[image]

I now have created an App services, and wish to utilize the same domain name with my application. I therefore, created an A record, a TXT record, and the CNAME record as well for for the domain name and for the subdomain www, but I am not able to validate it and get the domain ownership error.

[image]

Any Help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the NS Records mentioned in your first screenshot (Hope the screenshot is of the DNS Zone), has been mapped (correctly) to the domain name in the DNS record in the control panel of your domain registrar?

Comment: Thanks! There was a mismatch, which I corrected, and it is working properly.